# Push results of one to another job django-rq

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, django-rq

I'm building an application in which users' information are frequently updated from external APIs. For that, I'm using `django-rq`.

- The first job is scheduled once a day to get users who need to update their profiles.
- With each result returned by the first job, schedule another job to get new user information from remote API and update the user in my database.

  ```
  # tasks.py
  import requests
  from django_rq import job

  @job('default')
  def get_users_to_update():
      """Get a list of users to who need update"""
      users = User.objects.filter(some_condition_here...)
      return users

  @job('default')
  def remote_update_user(user):
      """Calls external API to get new user information"""
      url = 'http://somwhere.io/api/users/{}'.format(user.id)
      headers= {'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(user.access_token)}
      # Send the request, probably takes long time
      r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

      data = r.json()  # new user data
      for key, value in data.items():
          setattr(user, key, value)

      user.save()

      return user
  ```

I can schedule those two jobs like following:

```
    # update_info.py
    import django_rq

    scheduler = django_rq.get_scheduler('default')

    scheduler.schedule(
        scheduled_time=datetime.utcnow(),
        func=tasks.get_users_to_update,
        interval=24 * 60 * 60
    )

    scheduler.schedule(
        scheduled_time=datetime.utcnow(),
        func=tasks.remote_update_user,
        interval=24 * 60 * 60
    )
```

However, this is certainly not what I want. I'm wondering if there is any way in `django-rq` to notify when `get_users_to_update` is finished, get its results and schedule the `remote_update_user`.

`rq` allows `depends_on` for declaring the dependent job a submitted job, but it seems that such functionality isn't available in `django-rq`.

Comment: Have you found solution for your problem?

Comment: @Ivan I used `remote_update_user.delay(user)` at the end of `get_users_to_update`. This way, after the get function is finished, the `remote_update_user` is dispatched, and run with results from the `get_users_to_update` function.